# GCC cannot use option '-n1' when pip install biopython on aarch64 centos7

Tags: python, gcc, centos7, bioinformatics, biopython

gcc version 8.4.1
[enter image description here][1]

This is an aarch64 CentOS7 server. I'm trying to install Biopython==1.77 for Bio.Alphabat is removed after this version.

Conda only provided version 1.78 and 1.79 for me to install and
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ckx0.png

Comment: Please don't show images of text. [Edit] your question to include all text copy-pasted as text.

Comment: Why do you want to use Bio.Alphabet? It was removed because it is not needed and there are workarounds for any use cases

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.